# Reading /proc/mdstat

Tags: mdadm, raid5

I just built my first raid5 yesterday (with 4 hds) and was reading about monitoring with /proc/mdstat.  My understanding is an ideal dispaly with 4 drives should be [UUUU] however mine reads [UUU_].   See below:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid5 sde[4] sdc[1] sda[0] sdd[2]
      11720661504 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [UUU_]
      [==>..................]  recovery = 11.3% (442037248/3906887168) finish=7793.7min speed=7408K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

Is this normal since my raid is still syncing?  I can use fdisk on each drive to view the appropriate size so I don't believe I have any DOA drives.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is normal for a RAID5 array.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm).

> When creating a RAID5 array, mdadm will automatically create a degraded array with an extra spare drive. This is because building the spare into a degraded array is in general faster than resyncing the parity on a non-degraded, but not clean, array. This feature can be overridden with the --force option.

So, you most likely ran your command to create the array, it was created in the degraded state.  Now it is 'recovering' the parity drive.